# Finding the broken file in a corpus Python

Tags: python, nltk, corpus

I'm using Python's NLTK TaggedCorpusReader to create a corpus of text files.  However, one of the files is either not in utf-8 or has an unsupported character.  Is there any way to tell which file contains the problem?

Here is my code:

```
import nltk
corpus=nltk.corpus.TaggedCorpusReader("filepath", '.*.txt', encoding='utf-8') #I added the encoding when I saw some answer about that, but it doesn't seem to help
words=corpus.words()
for w in words:
    print(w)
```

My Error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: can you post your input file somewhere, we can help you check whether its an encoding problem afterwards. Also are you on python3?

Comment: @alvas I did some more digging and the problem was that the file wasn't encoded in utf-8.  And I am using Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify the file by reading the files one at a time, like this:

```
corpus = nltk.corpus.TaggedCorpusReader("filepath", r'.*\.txt', encoding='utf-8')

try: 
    for filename in corpus.fileids():
        words_ = corpus.words(filename)
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print("UnicodeDecodeError in", filename)
```

(Or you could just print each file name before you read it, and not even bother trapping the error.)

Once you find the file, you'll have to figure out the source of the problem. Is your corpus really utf-8 encoded? Perhaps it's using another, 8-bit encoding such as Latin-1 or whatever. Specifying an 8-bit encoding will not give you an error (there is no error checking in these formats), but you can ask python to print some lines and see if the selected encoding was correct.

If your corpus is almost entirely in English, you can search the file for lines containing non-ascii characters and print just these:

```
testreader = nltk.corpus.TaggedCorpusReader("filepath", r".*\.txt", encoding="Latin-1")

for line in testreader.raw(badfilename).splitlines():
    if re.search(r'[\x80-\xFF]', line)):
        print(line)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you!  I found the offending files and changed their encoding to utf-8 and that fixed the problem.  Thank you so much!